# How to call to a javascript file that in bundle in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a client script with deployment on customer, this client script need to call to a javascript file that in a bundle but I don't why it doesn't get it, the path is correct:

```
define(['N/record','/SuiteBundles/Bundle 510222/Customize UI/customize_ui.js'],
```

Any idea how to import it?